# "Message from webpage" Internet Explorer 8 (in compatibility mode) 

Tags: jquery, ie8-compatibility-mode

I'm getting some strange messages from Internet Explorer 8 when loading my latest web site project:

> No object with ID #body-news-content .post exist yet. Call curbeyCorners(setting, obj) when it is created.

The site is running on WordPress, using curveyCorners for roundcorners in Internet Explorer. I should probably mention that the site itself renders correctly, but for some reason Internet Explorer insists on giving me this message.

Here is a [screengrab](http://demo.carbonium.no/screengrab.png) of the image:

(Meta content: I can't post more than one link so if you would like to see the temp site in action I'll reply with a URL. Thanks you for any and all help.)

Comment: The screenshot url yields a 403

Comment: off-topic, but I'd recommend [CSS3Pie](http://www.css3pie/) instead of CurveyCorners -- better results and more standards-compliant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution myself. On the curveyCorners website (the instructions page), they reference a call to the `Alert()` function which is used to inform users when objects or elements using curveyCorners have not loaded yet. Why exactly this only happens in Internet Explorer I'm still unsure about.

Anyway, here is the solution! Add this bit of code to the header tag of your site and the `Alert()` warnings go away.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var curvyCornersVerbose = false;
</script>
```

I hope this helps others having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

By reading the error message, it seems that the curveyCorners script you are using is used to 'round' the corners of elements with class 'post' in the element of id 'body-news-content'. However it seems that at the time the curveyCorners script is launched, there is no such elements.

You should call the script later, before  for example, or in $(document).ready() if you are using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for for your reply. In regards to your answer i was thinking the same thing. The only problem is that curveyCorners works by adding its functions to any selector that has any of the different coner radius definitions. 

Example: 

.rounded {
  -moz-border-radius:3ex;
  -webkit-border-radius:3ex;
} 

Adding that and the link to the curveyCorners library creates the effect. So how do i make it load earlier in the DOM tree?

Comment: If you mean _later_, try to put the <script> tab just before </body>.

Comment: Sorry, i did mean later. I tried that but it appears that the script won't load at all now. I don't think WordPress accept the placement.

wordpress requires a different code:

<?php wp_enqueue_script("curvycorners", get_bloginfo("template_url") . "/js/curvycorners.js"); ?>